# Issue with Wacom Bamboo Fun Pen & Touch

Tags: 11.10, wacom, graphics-tablet

I'm running 11.10 and I've bought a Wacom Bamboo Fun Pen & Touch Tablet. I'm very happy with the Pen on Ubuntu, it's very responsive and works well for clicking and dragging etc.

The issue that I've got is that when using touch, nothing seems to work as it does elsewhere, for instance trying to click with touch just moves the cursor up about a bit and trying to scroll doesn't work but occasionally zooms.

Any advice?

Comment: I had the same problem with the same pen tablet (Wacom, Bamboo). I couldn't even install the software CD on Linux.  When I asked them, I've got the answer that it's not supported by Linux as well as Windows. If you read the system requirements, it has all versions of windows and Macintosh but no Linux versions.

Comment: The pen is working absolutely fine, it's just the touch that's the issue

Comment: Oh, it doesn't work for me! No idea then.

Answer (score 1):

I too have Oneiric and the same tablet. If it is one of the new series (mine is 00df, you can know it typing in the terminal "lsusb"). I have found one recent item on how to solve the problem. There is a repository for not to compile the driver and add them to the kernel. Here is the link: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1515562
 I have tried it and now the tablet works very well in ubuntu (also the touch). I have used it in Mypaint and inkscape. I have installed gimp 2.7.4 (because 2.6.x has a bug) and seems that can work, but I must learn how to setting the parameter.